# How to implement a scrollspy in react native with ScrollView?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a ScrollView component with different elements say:

```
<ScrollView>

    <Item1/>

    <Item2/>

    <Item3/>

</ScrollView>
```

I now have a tab which I need to highlight each tab item based on the current section the user is viewing in the scroll view. For example, if the user is viewing/scrolled to `<Item2/>` in the scroll view, then I should highlight item2 icon in the tab.

Also, if the user clicks on a tab item, it should automatically make the scrollview scroll to that respective item's section.

Is there any way to implement this scrollspy functionality in react native?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To achieve desired behavior you need to combine couple of things.

1. `ScrollView` has a method called [`scrollTo`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollto) which let's you scroll to the desired position of the content.
2. To be able to detect what is the `ScrollView`'s current position you need to use [`onScroll`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#onscroll) property. You can combine this property with [`scrollEventThrottle`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrolleventthrottle) to get a better accuracy.
3. To get the each item's position inside the `ScrollView` you need to implement [`onLayout`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout) property for each item.

Below is a small sample app to show how to implement above steps.

```
const Item = props => (
  <View
    style={{ minHeight: 500 }}
    onLayout={e => props.onItemLayout(e, props.index)}>
    <Text>{`Item ${props.index}`}</Text>
  </View>
);

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      sections: [1, 2, 3],
      currentSection: 1
    };
  }
  moveToSetion = section => {
    // scroll view to section
    this.scrollView.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: this.state[section], animated: true });
    // set state to current section
    this.setState({ currentSection: section });
  };
  onItemLayout = ({ nativeEvent: { layout: { x, y, width, height } } }, section) => {
    // setting each items position
    this.setState({ [section]: y });
  };
  onScroll = ({ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y, x } } }) => {
    let _currentSection;
    // loop sections to calculate which section scrollview is on
    this.state.sections.forEach((section) => {
      // adding 15 to calculate Text's height
      if((y + 15) > this.state[section]) _currentSection = section
    })
    // settint the currentSection to the calculated current section
    this.setState({ currentSection: _currentSection })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          {this.state.sections.map(section => (
            <Button
              key={section}
              title={`Section ${section}`}
              color={this.state.currentSection === section ? 'red' : 'blue'}
              onPress={() => this.moveToSetion(section)}
            />
          ))}
        </View>
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.scrollView}
          ref={ref => (this.scrollView = ref)}
          scrollEventThrottle={100}
          onScroll={this.onScroll}>
          {this.state.sections.map(section => (
            <Item
              key={section}
              index={section}
              onItemLayout={this.onItemLayout}
            />
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
  },
  scrollView: {
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15
  }
});
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Much better than the documentation written by my colleague on scrollspy. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: how is the same behaviour could be adjusted to SectionList Component?